# Change color of the prefix icon in a Flutter textfield using themes

Tags: flutter, themes, textfield

I would like to change the colour of the prefix icon in a textfield using themes.

I've tried this: -

```
  iconTheme: IconThemeData(
    color: Colors.red
  ),
```

But the above only changes the icons that are not in a textfield.
I've also tried setting the primary colour like this :-

```
 primaryColor: Colors.red,
```

But that only changes the focused colour of the icon.
How do I change the unfocused colour of the prefix icon using themes?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your App's **ThemeData** class:

```
iconTheme: IconThemeData(
  color: Colors.white
)
```

And then write this in your **TextField** widget

```
prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit,color: AppTheme.darkTheme.iconTheme.color)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, add color to just the specified icon as below:

```dart
prefixIcon: Icon(
 Icons.lock_outline,
 color: Colors.white
),
```